# How to contact Facebook Connect users through Facebook's API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

We have users that logged in to our website through Facebook Connect.  Now we'd like to contact those users about changes as we indicated in the signup process, but we don't have their email addresses.  Only their Facebook ids.

How can we contact them?  I understand Facebook removed 3rd parties' ability to send notifications through Facebook's API.  We can send them a message through the API either.

So I guess we're left with posting to their wall from a user account of ours.  I assume there's a low limit to how often we're allowed to do that and is that even permitted?  Or we can make an application request from this designated facebook user account which would show up in their notifications.

Finally, we could manually go to the user's profile page and then click the "send a message" button from our facebook user account...  A lot of manual work and I assume this is frowned upon as well.  Is there an easy way to find out the profile page URL from a Facebook id?

What's the best approach here where we don't break any rules?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting stream_publish extended permission in your profile then you can simply post on there wall see this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/

Alternatively this can be a better solution if the user do not granted any extended permission 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/livemessage.send/

Comment: interesting liveMessage feature, was unaware of that... nor have I seen that in action I think.  But then does the user get a popup message only on your site where you enable this?

Answer (score 0):

you should get  "offline_access" from the facebook user requests to post at anytime.